# how to randomize value from parameter field and use?

Tags: jmeter, clientid

[image: image1]

Hello,
i want to extract this client id and use it on the same place which is also generating in the same place.how can i do it. please provide any way if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you understand what does this `client_id` mean?

My expectation is that you shouldn't touch it, leave it as it is.

As per [documentation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/client-registration/client-id-secret/)

> **Client ID**
>
> The client_id is a public identifier for apps. Even though it’s public, it’s best that it isn’t guessable by third parties, so many implementations use something like a 32-character hex string. If the client ID is guessable, it makes it slightly easier to craft phishing attacks against arbitrary applications. It must also be unique across all clients that the authorization server handles.
>
> Here are some examples of client IDs from services that support OAuth 2.0:
>
> - Foursquare: ZYDPLLBWSK3MVQJSIYHB1OR2JXCY0X2C5UJ2QAR2MAAIT5Q
> - Github: 6779ef20e75817b79602
> - Google: 292085223830.apps.googleusercontent.com
> - Instagram: f2a1ed52710d4533bde25be6da03b6e3
> - SoundCloud: 269d98e4922fb3895e9ae2108cbb5064
> - Windows Live: 00000000400ECB04
> - Okta: 0oa2hl2inow5Uqc6c357

If you're using this `client_id` in multiple places in your script and want to declare it once to follow [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle - you can do this in [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)

Comment: thank you for this valuable information. currently, yes i am using in it in user defined variables. was trying if possible to parameterise it.